# preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array error

Tags: laravel-4

```
public function assignprocessing() {

    $newassignment= new DoctorAppointment();
    $newassignment->doctor_id=Session::get('doctorid');
    $newassignment->patient_id=Session::get('users.id');
    $newassignment->appointment_id=Session::get('appoint');
    $newassignment->save();

    if ($newassignment->save()) {
        return View::make('hospital.appointments');
    }
}
```

I am using values i had retrieved in another query, instead of rewriting them freshly, I used `Session::set` to save the values and 'Session::get' to retrieve them in the above query, I get the error parameter mismatch

Comment: Please post your `Session:set()` code.

Comment: Session::set('users.id', $appointments);
Session::set('appoint', $appointments);

Comment: $hosi = DoctorHospital::where('doctor_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first()->hospital_id;
  $appointments= DB::table('appointments')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'appointments.patient_id')
      ->where('appointments.hospital_id', '=', $hosi)
      ->where('users.type', 1)
      ->select('users.firstname', 'users.lastname', 'appointments.about', 'appointments.message', 'appointments.created_at','appointments.id AS appoint')
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
      ->get();
     Session::set('users.id', $appointments);
     Session::set('appoint', $appointments);

Comment: You can't directly get `doctorid` from Session.